# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Model ' before initialization

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, belongs-to, has-one

I am facing an issue in defining the relationship between models in the Nodejs express app. I have two models one is Contact and the other is Conversation, I want to define a one-to-one relationship between them. Contact hasOne Conversation and Conversation belongsTo Contact. I am using Sequelize as ORM.

Nodejs version - v14.15.1(Using ECMAScript )
Sequelize - 6.5.0

Contact Model

```
import sequelize from "sequelize";
import database from "../config/database.js";
import Conversation from "./conversation.js";

const { DataTypes } = sequelize;

const Contact = database.define("contact", {
  opted_in: {
    default: false,
    type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  },
  uuid: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  country_code: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  mobile_number: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    isEmail: true,
  },
});

Contact.hasOne(Conversation);

export default Contact;
```

Conversation Model

```
import sequelize from "sequelize";
import database from "../config/database.js";
import Contact from "./contact.js";

const { DataTypes } = sequelize;

const Conversation = database.define("conversation", {
  uuid: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  last_message_created_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  last_inbound_message_created_at: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  unread_messages_count: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  status: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    // values: ['unattended', 'attended', 'inprocess'],
    default: 1,
  },
});

Conversation.belongsTo(models.Contact, {
  allowNull: false,
  foreignKey: {
    name: "uni_contact_id",
  },
  as: "unilodgers",
});

export default Conversation;
```

On starting my application I am getting the below error -

Contact.hasOne(Conversation);
^

**ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Conversation' before initialization**

Comment: I think you have a circular dependency error: you can check some example on this other SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163520/nodejssequelize-referenceerror-cannot-access-modelname-before-initializat

Comment: I saw that solution but the answer given to that is not a good one, I have also commented out about the drawbacks of that solution.