# Sequelize Cannot Access "projectuser" before initialization

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

sirs. I have 2 models in sequelize ,`Project` and `User`. Relationship between this two models is many-to-many. Fot this relation, I have created `projectuser`. But when i trying to insert into`projectuser`  console gives me `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'projectuser' before initialization` error. [[NodeJs][Sequelize] ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ModelName' before initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163520/nodejssequelize-referenceerror-cannot-access-modelname-before-initializat) I have tried this solution but i think it is too complex solution. Can you please help me?

```
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Project extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      const { User, Issue, projectuser } = models;

      this.belongsToMany(User, {
        as: "project_users",
        foreignKey: "project_id",
        through: "projectuser",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });

      this.hasMany(Issue, {
        as: "project_issues",
        foreignKey: "project_id",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
  }
  Project.init(
    {
      project_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      projectname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      },
      projecturl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Project",
    }
  );
  return Project;
};


const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      const { Commet, Project, Issue, projectuser, issueuser } = models;

      this.hasMany(Commet, {
        foreignKey: "user_id",
        as: "user_commets",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });

      this.belongsToMany(Project, {
        as: "project_user",
        foreignKey: "user_id",
        through: "projectuser",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });

      this.belongsToMany(Issue, {
        as: "user_issues",
        foreignKey: "user_id",
        through: issueuser,
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },

      role: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          roleValidator(role) {
            let rolet = role.toLowerCase();

            if (roles[rolet] === undefined) {
              throw new Error("Invalid Role");
            }
          },
        },
      },
      username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      usersurname: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      avatarURL: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        validate: {
          passwordValidator(password) {
            if (password.length <= 5) {
              throw new Error("Cannot be less than 5 characters");
            }
          },
        },
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        validate: { isEmail: true },
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
  return User;
};

const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class projectuser extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  projectuser.init({
    deneme: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'projectuser',
  });
  return projectuser;
};
```

Comment: Make sure that all models were initialed before calling their `associate` methods